# Linear independence of backward weighted shifts

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let  $\{w_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of bounded non-zero positive real numbers and $T^{*} : H \rightarrow{H}$ such that
\begin{align*}
        T^{*}(e_{0})=0~,~T^{*}(e_{n}) = w_{n-1}e_{n-1}~,~n\geq 0.
\end{align*}

Then is it true that, if $M\subset H$ be a closed subset such that $T^{*}(M)\subseteq M$ and there exists some $x\in M$ such that $x=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{i}e_{i}$, i.e., $x$ is not the linear combination of any finitely many elements of orthonormal basis $\{e_{i}\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$, then $M$ turns out be an infinite dimensional space as $\big\{x, T^{*}x ,\ldots, T^{*n}x,\ldots\big\}\subseteq M$ is linearly independent ?

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $w_n = 2$ for all $n$, $x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty 2^{-i} e_i$. Then $T^*x = \frac12x$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there any condition on $w_{n}$ so that they become linearly indepedent? for example if I take  $w_{n}$ square summable.